# How do you prove that $\sin(x + \pi) = -\sin(x)$ graphically?

Tags: trigonometry

How can one prove that $\sin(x + \pi) = -\sin(x)$ graphically? I'm learning trig right now and I'm having trouble understanding this concept, please help. Thanks!

Comment: How has $\sin(x)$ been defined you you? Through the unit circle?

Comment: Shifting the graph of $y=\sin{(x)}$ to the left by $\pi$ units is equivalent to flipping the graph over the $x$ axis.

Comment: In general, be careful with proving something by a picture although in this case, it can be done. Usually, a picture gives an idea which is later verified rigorously (or perhaps refuted)

Answer (score 0):

The $sin()$ is defined as the "height" of the circle with radius one. Hence, to answer your question we  either look at the left or the right picture[image: sinDefinition] 
On the unit circle (left picture) we see that the "heights" at $\alpha$ and $\alpha + \pi = \alpha + 180°$ are equal, except for a minus sign. The right picture just changes the way this result is presented.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a graphical way, but this is a sensible way to prove this result. Define $\sin x=\frac{1}{2i}(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})$. Then it is easy to see (as $e^{\pi i}=-1$) that $\sin (\pi+x)=\frac{1}{2i}(e^{i\pi}e^{ix}-e^{-i\pi}e^{-ix})$, that is $\sin(\pi+x)=-\frac{1}{2i}(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})$. And $-\sin x=-\frac{1}{2i}(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})$.